# iPhone: Setting the SelectedTabIndex does not highlight TabItem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin.ios

When in code I set the SelectedTabIndex of a uitabbarcontroller, it faithfully changes the displayed tab, but the TabItem does not highlight. I have to manually touch it to turn the TabItem "Blue" and highlighted.

Is there a way to force the TabItem to be highlighted?

We've tried this:

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        this.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.SelectedViewController = this.ViewControllers[0];
        this.TabBar.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    }
```

Comment: Try calling setNeedsDisplay on the uitabbarcontroller's tabbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In my Child Views, the UITabItem had to be set to enabled:

```
    UITabBarItem t; 
    public override UITabBarItem TabBarItem
    {
        get { 
            if(t==null)
                t= new UITabBarItem ("Baha'i", UIImage.FromFile ("Images/Unity_in_Diversity.png"), 0);
            t.Enabled=true;
            return t; 
        }
        set { base.TabBarItem = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UITabBarController` `selectedViewController` property instead.